# Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label '{33}' will be lost

Tags: equations

I have this code and

```
Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label '{33}' will be lost.
```

error: can anyone help me?

```
\begin{align}
\label{33}
\begin{split}
\alpha_{ng}^{\min}-\alpha_{ng}^{\max}+\gamma_n\leq C_{ng}\forall g\in\Omega^{G-n},\forall n\in\Omega^N
\end{split}
\label{34}
\begin{split}
\beta_\ell^{\min}-\beta_\ell^{\max}+\frac{\epsilon_\ell^{\min}}{\beta_\ell}-\frac{\epsilon_\ell^{\max}}{\beta_\ell}-\gamma_{n}=0
\forall l\in\Omega^L\mid \textit{FB}(\ell)=n
\end{split}
\\
\label{35}
\begin{split}
&\beta_\ell^{\min}-\beta_\ell^{\max}+\frac{\epsilon_\ell^{\min}}{\beta_\ell}-\frac{\epsilon_\ell^{\max}}{\beta_\ell}+\gamma_{n}=0\\
\forall \ell\in\Omega^L\mid \textit{TB}(\ell)=n
\end{split}
\\
\label{36}
\begin{split}
&-\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{ \ell \in\Omega^L\st\\ \textit{FB}(\ell)=n}}}\epsilon_\ell^{\min}+\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{ \ell \in\Omega^L\st\\ \textit{TB}(\ell)=n}}}\epsilon_\ell^{\min}
+\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{ \ell \in\Omega^L\st\\ \textit{FB}(\ell)=n}}}\epsilon_\ell^{\max}-\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{ \ell \in\Omega^L\st\\ \textit{TB}(\ell)=n}}}\epsilon_\ell^{\max}
+\\\delta_n^{\min}-\delta_n^{\max}=0~~\forall n\in \Omega^N
\end{split}
\\
\label{37}
&\gamma_n \leq \textit{VOLL}_n~~\forall n\in\Omega^N\\
\label{38}
&\bar{D}_{n}-\widehat D_{n}\leq\widetilde D_{n}\leq\bar{D}_{n}+\widehat D_{n}\\
\label{39}
&\sum_{ n\in\Omega^N}|\frac{\widetilde D_{n}-\bar D_{n}}{\widehat D_{n}}|\leq\textit{DR}
%\end{flalign}
\\
\label{40}
\begin{split}
&\alpha_{ng}^{\min},\alpha_{ng}^{\max}\geq 0\quad\forall g \in \Omega^{G-n},\forall n \in \Omega^{N};\\
\beta_\ell^{\min},\beta_\ell^{\max},  \epsilon_\ell^{\min},\epsilon_\ell^{\max}\geq 0\quad\forall l \in \Omega^{L};\\
\delta_n^{\min},\delta_n^{\max}\geq 0\quad\forall n \in \Omega^{N};
\gamma _n \in R\quad\forall n \in \Omega^{N};\\
\bar{D}_{n} \in R\quad\forall n \in \Omega^{N}\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Comment: `33` is not a good name for a label, but in the extract you show us it's only there once. Do you have it somewhere else too?

Comment: Numbering the labels is exactly what you shouldn't do. The precise reason to use labels is to use a symbolic name to call, so it's not affected by the place / order / situation. Using numbers is what you shouldn't do, better a keyword that *represents* that.

Comment: @Sigur that is not the "used twice" warning, it is the error (tex stops) that amsmath is discarding an illegal label

Comment: Ow, `Multiple \label's:` is a very strange way to show the error... lol I'll delete my comment.

Comment: The same error in my Beamer document was caused by using the `\label` in `align*.`

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{align}
\label{33}
\begin{split}
\alpha_{ng}^{\min}-\alpha_{ng}^{\max}+\gamma_n\leq C_{ng}\forall g\in\Omega^{G-n},\forall n\in\Omega^N
\end{split}
\\
\label{34}
\begin{split}
\beta_\ell^{\min}-\beta_\ell^{\max}+\frac{\epsilon_\ell^{\min}}{\beta_\ell}-\frac{\epsilon_\ell^{\max}}{\beta_\ell}-\gamma_{n}=0\\\forall l\in\Omega^L\mid \textit{FB}(\ell)=n
\end{split}
\\
\label{35}
\begin{split}
\beta_\ell^{\min}-\beta_\ell^{\max}+\frac{\epsilon_\ell^{\min}}{\beta_\ell}-\frac{\epsilon_\ell^{\max}}{\beta_\ell}+\gamma_{n}=0\\
\forall \ell\in\Omega^L\mid \textit{TB}(\ell)=n
\end{split}
\\
\label{36}
\begin{split}
-\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{ \ell \in\Omega^L\st\\ \textit{FB}(\ell)=n}}}\epsilon_\ell^{\min}+\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{ \ell \in\Omega^L\st\\ \textit{TB}(\ell)=n}}}\epsilon_\ell^{\min}
+\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{ \ell \in\Omega^L\st\\ \textit{FB}(\ell)=n}}}\epsilon_\ell^{\max}-\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{ \ell \in\Omega^L\st\\ \textit{TB}(\ell)=n}}}\epsilon_\ell^{\max}
+\\\delta_n^{\min}-\delta_n^{\max}=0~~\forall n\in \Omega^N
\end{split}
\\
\label{37}
&\gamma_n \leq \textit{VOLL}_n~~\forall n\in\Omega^N\\
\label{38}
&\bar{D}_{n}-\widehat D_{n}\leq\widetilde D_{n}\leq\bar{D}_{n}+\widehat D_{n}\\
\label{39}
&\sum_{ n\in\Omega^N}|\frac{\widetilde D_{n}-\bar D_{n}}{\widehat D_{n}}|\leq\textit{DR}
%\end{flalign}
\\
\label{40}
\begin{split}
&\alpha_{ng}^{\min},\alpha_{ng}^{\max}\geq 0\quad\forall g \in \Omega^{G-n},\forall n \in \Omega^{N};\\
&\beta_\ell^{\min},\beta_\ell^{\max},  \epsilon_\ell^{\min},\epsilon_\ell^{\max}\geq 0\quad\forall l \in \Omega^{L};\\
&\delta_n^{\min},\delta_n^{\max}\geq 0\quad\forall n \in \Omega^{N};
\gamma _n \in R\quad\forall n \in \Omega^{N};\\
&\bar{D}_{n} \in R\quad\forall n \in \Omega^{N}\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Just forgetting \\ after one of  the \end{split}.

Comment: Just to add a possible reason for others (not in the code above) to get that error message - using an environment's `*` version instead of the non-`*` one while trying to label specific lines (more than one, which labels just the environment itself) in it.

Comment: @et_l: Exactly, this happened to me recently. What took me a lot of head scratching to realize is that I used align*, label but forgot to put \numberthis. What is confusing is that Latex did not complain at the right line no: it complained at my next such usage, rather that the culprit. (I used \input, which may have further complicated things a bit.)

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is twofold. Firstly, the "label's" error message could be more specific, more clear. And secondly, this happens because of a misunderstanding of the rules regarding the use of align and align* blocks. Consider you put an "align*" block (let's called it block "A") with 2 equations, and you label the last one. Then you use an "align" block "B" with 2 equations, and again you label only the last one. Finally you put a third "align" block "C" with both labelled equations. Something like this,

```
\begin{align*}
x &= 1 \\
x &= 1  \label{EQ:a2}
\end{align*}

\begin{align}
x &= 1 \\
x &= 1  \label{EQ:b2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
x &= 1 \label{EQ:c1}\\
x &= 1 \label{EQ:c2}
\end{align}
```

It complies with no errors. Now here comes the magic, if you label first eq of block B,

```
\begin{align}
x &= 1 \label{EQ:b1} \\
x &= 1 \label{EQ:b2}
\end{align}
```

Then you have the label's error. Now you can do two things for good compilation: a) You delete the label "EQ:a2" of block A, and it compiles again, OR b) You delete again label "EQ:b1" in block B. Strange, huh? The curious thing is that Block "C" have all equations labelled without errors.

I suppose the most orthodox solution is convert block "A" from "align*" into "align" and declare \nonumber in the first equation, like this,

```
\begin{align}
x &= 1 \nonumber\\
x &= 1 \label{EQ:a2}
\end{align}
```

because in this case, you can label both equations EQ:b1,EQ:b2 of the block "B" without the "label's" error. In any case, my personal opinion is that the label's error message should be more clear with this regard. I hope this contributes to a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: You should simply not `\label` an equation with no number and no tag.