# Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:natural_frequency' will be lost

Tags: cross-referencing, align

I've marked lines where I get an error Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:natural_frequency' will be lost. I have only 1 label that is named `\label{eq:natural_frequency}`.
Added MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Problem 7.19}
\begin{align}\label{eq:natural_frequency}
\omega_{n} &= \frac{\pi}{t_{r}\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}} \nonumber \\
\omega_{n} &= \frac{\pi}{0.2\sqrt{1-0.707^{2}}} \nonumber \\
\omega_{n} &= 22.21 \nonumber
\end{align}\\

\subsection{Part (a)}\label{subsec:730a}
Using the given equations:
\begin{align}\label{eq:given}
\frac{dx_{1}(t)}{dt} &= -x_{1} + 5x_{2} \nonumber \\
\frac{dx_{2}(t)}{dt} &= -6x_{1}(t) - k_{1}x_{1}(t) + r(t) \nonumber
\end{align} %ERROR ON THIS LINE

We can now find the characteristic equation:

\begin{align}\label{eq:ch_eq_1}
\begin{vmatrix}
s + 1 & -5 \\
6 + k_{1} & s + k_{2}
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align} %ERROR ON THIS LINE

\end{document}
```

As in the answer by Willie Wong.

Suggestion was to remove `\nonumber` to have a reference point.

However, I wonder why latex does not show an error in the align labeled `natural frequency`. It also contains `\nonumber` for each line.

[image]

Comment: Please add a MWE to your question

Comment: For your updated question: the reason that the errors shows on the "wrong line" is a side effect of the complicated way `amsmath` typesets math material (it does a two-pass process where it first do a dummy trial to measure how wide things are and then do it for real). [It has come up before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209135/package-amsmath-error-multiple-labels-label-33-will-be-lost#comment1160537_209137). I'll edit a oversimplistic explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you expect will happen when you tell LaTeX to both

- label an equation, and
- not number an equation ?

If you are going to `\label` an `\begin{align}`, the line that `\label` is on should not also have `\nonumber`. Removing those `\nonumber` incantations fixes the errors.

---

That said, It appears that you using the labels to refer to an entire group of equations, rather than a specific one? Then maybe it is better to use

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:???}
   \begin{aligned}
       aligned material here
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:grp:???}
   \begin{align}
       aligned material
   \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

The first option will generate something that looks like
[image]

The second option I think looks better.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Problem 7.19}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:natural_frequency}
        \begin{align}
\omega_{n} &= \frac{\pi}{t_{r}\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}} \\
\omega_{n} &= \frac{\pi}{0.2\sqrt{1-0.707^{2}}}  \\
\omega_{n} &= 22.21 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

Just to see what references look like: \eqref{eq:natural_frequency}.

\end{document}
```

---

The OP also asked why the errors appear on the wrong line.
This is due to the complicated way in which AMS math typesets displayed math, which involves a two-pass process to first measure and then print for real. (The following is not 100% accurate, but close enough to the truth for a non-technical explanation.)

As part of this process, the code first reads all the `\label`s and then puts them aside for later processing (since they have no role in  deciding the spacing of equations, as they don't generate printed matter). These are then processed when the corresponding equation numbers are printed.

However, when you do also a `\nonumber`, the equation numbers are never printed, and hence the `\label`s are not processed. And the way the code works means that they ***remain in the queue to be processed***.

The next time another display math environment occurs in which you placed a `\label`, when queueing the label to be processed, amsmath discovers that there is still an unprocessed label, so it **incorrrectly** assumes that's due to you accidentally throwing two `\label`s on the same line (instead of having a leftover `\label` from earlier). It decides to be nice and warn you about it then. Which is why the warning appears to happen a bit late.

Incidentally, [campa's patch here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653587/119) has the side effect of clearing the queue of "yet to be processed labels" when you close the `align` environment. So if you include the patch, you will find that your original code will compile fine (with no warning at all), but with the two relevant `\label`s silently ignored. Whether this is a better outcome is debatable.

Comment: I expect anything... 
Helped with a second error but not with a first error (\label{subsec:730a})

Comment: I get no errors about `\label{subsec:730a}` if I either (a) remove `\label{eq:natural_frequency}` AND `\label{eq:given}`, or (b) remove the `\nonumber` from the first lines of the corresponding `\begin{align}`.

Comment: If I put align that is labeled `given` above align `natural frequency` without removing `\nonumber` there will be no error

Comment: I do not understand your most recent comment. If it is a comment on your original question, please edit it (with more details), into the question statement. If it is about the answer I shared, please provide more details on why my answer isn't sufficient for your needs.

Comment: +1 To be fair, I explicitly warn that I don't feel comfortable with the patch... `;-)`

Comment: @campa I know: that's why I tried it. (I also tried egreg's, which does nothing in this case.) `:-)`